# Mystic output of Error Object in Node

Tags: javascript, node.js

Im reading this article: 
http://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/errors/what-is-the-error-object

and trying to analyse the `Error` object with this code.

```
var error = new Error("The error message");
console.log(error);
```

When i run this code in Node I dont get the output expected. According to NodeJitsu the output should be a javascript object with methods and properties, like this:

```
{ stack: [Getter/Setter],
  arguments: undefined,
  type: undefined,
  message: 'The error message' }
```

Instead i get this strange output:

```
[Error: The error message]
```

Why is this? Why square brackets, as this indicate that the `Error` is an Array.
And where are the rest of the expected methods and properties?

Comment: You might want to read this: http://massalabs.com/dev/2013/10/17/handling-errors-in-nodejs.html